# ld: file not found: @executable_path/InDesignModel.framework/Versions/A/InDesignModel for architecture x86_64" error

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am trying to compile Indesign plugin code using Xcode 7.0 and MAC 10.10.5. But I am getting "ld: file not found: @executable_path/InDesignModel.framework/Versions/A/InDesignModel for architecture x86_64" error.

I have spent lot of time to resolve it without any luck.

Answer (score 1):

There is a missing library. Executables using dynamic libraries have both a list of those libraries, and possible paths to search when looking for them, called the *run path list*. The list of libraries can be either full or relative paths. If the paths are relative, the linker searches for them under each element of the run path list. (You can see the list of expected libraries with `otool -L`.)

The `@executable_path` is a variable that the dynamic linker replaces with the full path to the executable when doing this searching. So the linker is looking for the library at `/path/to/App.app/Contents/MacOS/app_executable/InDesignModel.framework/Versions/A/InDesignModel`, but it's not there.

The solution is to update the run time path list of the executable, using `install_name_tool`. You would do something like:

```
$ install_name_tool -add_rpath /path/to/InDesignModel app_binary
```

Alternatively, you can add to the `@rpath` directly during compilation, by adding the link flags `-Wl,-rpath,/path/to/InDesignModel`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly link with the InDesignModel framework, make sure this:

-framework InDesignModel

Is in your link command. Or add InDesignModel.framework in Xcode.

This fixes it for me in Xcode 7 and it's a behaviour change from Xcode 6.